# Existence of 1-complemented hyperplanes in finite dimensional normed spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, projection

Let $X$ be a $d$-dimensional normed space and $M$ a subspace of $X$, then we say that $M$ is *1-complemented* if there exists a linear projection $P :X \rightarrow X$ such that $P(X)=M$ and $\|P\|=1$.

What I wish to know is whether there always exists a $(d-1)$-dimensional subspace that is 1-complemented. It is a known result by Kakutani that $X$ is Euclidean if and only if all subspaces are 1-complemented (in fact we only require that all 2D subspaces be 1-complemented) and so in some way these spaces are special. If anyone knows of any such results I would be much appreciative.

Comment: Every subspace of a finite dimensional space is complemented, whatever its dimension. The question of complementarity arises in infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Chrystomath That is true but they are not all 1-complemented, it is a stronger property and so is a non-trivial property for finite dimensional spaces

Comment: No, in general there isn't one. Think of a space with a smooth norm and consider the gradient map $F(x) = \nabla (\|x\|^2)$. The existence of a norm-1 projection implies that $F$ maps some hyperplane to a hyperplane. This is not going to happen for a generic smooth map (even constrained by being the gradient of a convex function).